# admob ads on codename one apps and GDPR

Tags: admob, codenameone

i want to add admob banner to my codename one apps. but now google request that apps is need to be gdpr compliant. So, do i need to show dialog at start app, that my app use admob ads? if yes, how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Our support for admob pre-dated the advent of the GDPR so it's possible the library itself will need an update as I'm not an expert in GDPR.

As far as I understand GDPR (IANAL) is that on app launch you need to inform the user of the data that you would be collecting. Which is really the data admob is collecting in this case. I'm guessing this is listed somewhere in their site. Notice that if a user refuses the data collection the app should still function and show more generic ads.

About doing this in Codename One. Showing a dialog on startup means you first show the form then use a `callSerially` or `UITimer` to show a `Dialog` the first time around. You can store the consent state in the `Preferences` class.

The problem is the no-consent mode we don't have an API for that and it would be problematic since that old admob approach was implemented as a "seamless" build hint.

We have an [admob cn1lib](https://github.com/shannah/admobfullscreen-codenameone) which should probably work with GDPR and should allow more flexibility in this regard as it's implemented on top of native and should be easy to customize. However, we only support full screen ads in that version. From my conversation with developers it's pretty clear that banner ads don't make any money so full screen is pretty much the only viable option.